# Pass the Parsed Data to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, afnetworking-2

I'm a junior level developer and I'm stuck at this very simple thing which I'm unable to figure out.
I've a class which is `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` extended. Means it's `@interface apiClient : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` in this class I've all my code which fetch images from Imgur API and using `AFNetworking` I've parsed the data upto a level where I start getting only the link of the images.
Now the `rootViewController` which is a `UICollectionViewController` extended. In it's `viewDidLoad` I send a call to my APIClient and it start moving from methods to methods and finally give me an `NSMutableArray` which contains the images link I'll use in the `UIImageView` of my `CollectionViewCell`.
**The Question is** I'm using this to send the final links back to my `rootViewController` i.e. `GalleryCollectionViewController`

```
 GalleryCollectionViewController *gcvc = [[GalleryCollectionViewController alloc] init];
    [gcvc recieveGalleryImagesLinks:galleryImgLinkArr];
```

The problem is that in `gcvc` it calls `numberOfItemsInSection` before it can get any response from the API. So that means the count goes out zero and hence it is not displaying the data. So  how can I get it to get the API call from `apiClient` class first and then make the `viewController`. I hope I've clearly stated my problem and if there is a need of sharing any more code I'll do it.

**UPDATE**
After authorization this methods gets the gallery images:

```
- (void)galleryAlbum:(NSString *)ID {

NSLog(@"ID is %@", ID);

[self GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@3/gallery/album/%@", self.baseURL,ID] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    self.galleryData = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

    galleryDataArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    galleryDataArr = [self.galleryData valueForKey:@"data"];

    galleryImagesArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    galleryImagesArr = [galleryDataArr valueForKey:@"images"];

    galleryImgLinkArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    galleryImgLinkArr = [galleryImagesArr valueForKey:@"link"];

    GalleryCollectionViewController *gcvc = [[GalleryCollectionViewController alloc] init];
    [gcvc recieveGalleryImagesLinks:galleryImgLinkArr];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Failed #2");

    }];
}
```

Here gcvc is receiving the array with images link and then reloading the collection view as:

```
    -(void)recieveGalleryImagesLinks:(NSMutableArray *)array
{
    self.imageLinks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:array];
    NSLog(@"Array: %@",self.imageLinks);
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

But it's giving "UICollectionView: must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter" although the array is not empty.

Comment: Update your question with the relevant code that gets the data. You need to reload the collection (on the main thread) when the data is retrieved.

Comment: You are creating a new view controller instead of accessing the existing view controller.

Comment: Hi friend, dont allocate your view controller again and again, just call the [collectionview reloadData] to refresh your collection view data. Also use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_mainqueue... Method inside your Api call request for updating  your view related code.

Comment: @Microprocessor8085 can you code an example in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

This line of code below is incorrect:

```
GalleryCollectionViewController *gcvc = [[GalleryCollectionViewController alloc] init]; 
[gcvc recieveGalleryImagesLinks:galleryImgLinkArr];
```

You need to use a blocks or delegate approach here which will pass back the array back to your collectionViewController and reload the collecrionView.

Even your method call from API class seems to be correct for delegate approach but make it a protocal method. This way you need not have to change much. It will be something like below:

```
    [self.delegate recieveGalleryImagesLinks:galleryImgLinkArr
```

And when are calling API and is waiting for response show activityIndicator for loading data.

Comment: I've tried doing it with `@protocol` like you suggested but there seems to be a problem `No type or protocol named` here is the link of it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827903/no-type-or-protocol-named