# No type or protocol named

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

After searching of an the answer to this I found many related questions but after implementing them I am still unable to get rid of this error.
I've a class which is of `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` type. In this class `.h` file right after the Import statements end I have written `@protocol apiClientDelegate;` and in the `@interface` there is a `@property (weak) id<apiClientDelegate>delegate;` and after it `@end` I've written:

```
@protocol apiClientDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)finalImageURLs:(NSMutableArray*)array;
@end
```

So in another class which is a `UICollectionViewController` I've written it as `@interface GalleryCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController <apiClientDelegate>` and it is still showing this error. Here are the screenshots:
[image: this is how I'm setting the protocol]
and in the class where it is giving the error:
[image]

**UPDATE**

 After one of the comment I added `@protocol apiClientDelegate;` in the `GalleryCOllectionViewController` but now it started showing this warning and the method is not bein executed:
[image]

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? The screenshot does't show it.

Comment: @CrimsonChris it `No type or protocol named apiClientDelegate` in my GalleryCollectionViewController` class

Comment: Did you remember to import the header where the protocol is defined?

Comment: Have you imported 'apiClientDelegate' protocol in your GalleryCollectionViewController class?

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan I've `#import "ImgurAPIClient.h"` in my `GalleryCollectionViewController` class

Comment: You use forward declaration, it is not enough. Import protocol too.

Comment: Make sure you're importing the file that has the protocol definition. Make sure the file you're importing it into is the one with the error.

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan how should I import it then?

Comment: @CrimsonChris I'm importing `#import "ImgurAPIClient.h"` in the class where I'm using the delagate method

Comment: In your GalleryCollectionViewController.h file just add @protocol apiClientDelegate; Also think about names collision - actually it is not good practise to give protocol name in lowercase.

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan Thanks :)

Comment: Have I helped you?

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan it started showing the warning `Cannot find protocol definition for 'apiClientDelegate'` and it is now executing the delegate method.